# Complete camunda user task on springboot

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have run a Camunda server using spring boot and I can hit its API on my localhost to start a process, complete user tasks, etc.
I am looking for a way to complete a user task from within the Camunda server. I found a way to start a process like this:

```java
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processName, variables);
```

However, I could not find about how to complete a process. If I use the rest API it will be done in two step:

- Get the task id using `localhost:8080/engine-rest/task?definitionKey={{taskDefinitionKey}}&processInstanceId={{processInstanceId}}`
- Compltete the task with POST to `localhost:8080/engine-rest/task/{{taskId}}/complete`

How can I do the same from the java code (not from the API)? Since it weird to call itself functionality through Rest API instead of invoking the code. I believe the Rest API is calling some code in the system, I want to use that directly instead of using API. I have searched the Camunda documentation but haven't found anything.

My case is, this Camunda server will listen to a message broker and start a process or complete a user task, etc when a particular message is received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to do it, I can do it like this:

```
public void completeUserTask(String processInstanceId, String taskName, Map<String, Object> variables) {
    // taskService is instance of org.camunda.bpm.engine.TaskService
    String taskId = taskService.createTaskQuery()
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
            .list()
            .stream()
            .filter(task -> task.getTaskDefinitionKey().equals(taskName))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                    String.format("Could not find task with name %s on processInstanceId %s",
                            taskName,
                            processInstanceId))).getId();
    taskService.complete(taskId, variables);
}
```

Comment: how u get the processInstanceId ?

Comment: i am getting taskService as null

Answer (score 2):

This would be a better solution as it filters on DB level instead of iterating through all found tasks on the client. It is also simpler and considers only active tasks.

```
String taskId = taskService.createTaskQuery()
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
            .taskDefinitionKey(taskName)
            .active().singleResult().getId();
```